# Delete row and referencing rows in another table in SQLite 3

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite to play around and learn some more SQL. I have a SQLite 3 database populated like this:

```
create table playlist (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text);

create table playlistitem (id integer primary key autoincrement, 
    playlist_id integer, name text);

insert into playlist (name) values ("Moss");
insert into playlist (name) values ("Jen");

insert into playlistitem (playlist_id, name) values (1, "Roy");
insert into playlistitem (playlist_id, name) values (1, "Richmond");
insert into playlistitem (playlist_id, name) values (2, "Denholm");
```

Great, now I have two playlist items in the `"Moss"` playlist, `"Roy"` and `"Richmond"`; I have one item in the `"Jen"` playlist: `"Denholm"`.

What I'd like to do is delete the `"Moss"` playlist and all of its items with a single query.

I saw something like this, which fails for me:

```
delete playlist, playlistitem from playlist
    inner join playlistitem on playlistitem.playlist_id = playlist.id
    where playlist.name = "Moss";
```

Failure:

```
Error: near "playlist": syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite doesn't support `join` in `delete` statement. You have to use separate query that deletes from second table based on `playlist_id`, making a delete trigger on `playlist`, or make that reference a foreign key with `on delete cascade`:

```
create table playlistitem (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    playlist_id integer, name text,
    foreign key(playlist_id) references playlist(id) on delete cascade);
```

and then just using `delete from playlist where name='Moss'`.

Don't forget to enable foreign keys - `pragma foreign_keys=1` (you have to re-enable this on each sqlite connection, e.g. as the first command after connecting).